# google OAuth 2 new tokens always expired

Tags: php, google-oauth, gmail-api

I have completed the authorization steps where google asks for permission for the account and asks the user to verify, it returns access token, refresh token the type bearer.

Then I save the tokens in DB.
In a different php file I use this code:

```
require __DIR__ . '/foo/Google/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId("foo.apps.googleusercontent.com");
$client->setClientSecret("foo");
$client->setAccessToken($access_token);
$expired = $client->isAccessTokenExpired();
if($expired == 1)
{
$new_token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($refresh_token);
print_r($new_token);
$access_token = $new_token['access_token'];
send("UPDATE `foo_table` SET `access_token`='$access_token' WHERE `foo` = '$foo'");
$client->setAccessToken($access_token);
$expired = $client->isAccessTokenExpired();
echo $expired;
} 
if($expired == 0)
{ 
code..
```

I always get a new token, and the same initial refresh token, but it’s always expired, In the same page and when refreshed (Using the stored token). The php is in the authorized Uris of the google api

```
Array
(
[access_token] = foobar
[token_type] = Bearer
[expires_in] = 3600
[created] = 1522234588
[refresh_token] = Foobar
)
1 (Expired)
```

I’m using it for gmail api, the initial scopes:

```
$client->addScope("https://mail.google.com/");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand the usage of access token and refresh token.   There is no point in saving the access token to your database.  Access tokens are only good for one hour. You should be saving the refresh token.

When ever your code needs to run you take your refresh token and request a new access token.

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); 
                $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();              
            }
```

Code ripped from [Oauth2Authentication.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Drive%20API/v3/Oauth2Authentication.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want/need to store the access token in the database, here's what you can do. Since the access token is an array that includes the `access_token`, `expires_in`, `scope`, `token_type`, etc... you will have to store the whole array in the database. What you can do is this:

```
$accessToken = $client->getAccessToken();
$serializedAccessToken = serialize($accessToken);

$insertIntoDatabase = insert($serializedAccessToken)......
```

Now if you want to retrieve the access token from the database and check if it has expired or not, you can do this:

```
$getAccessToken = getFromDatabase...
$accessTokenArray = unserialize($getAccessToken);

if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
}
```